# Consuming JSON Object with Spring MVC

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

I have trouble consuming a JSON object from within my Spring MVC app. I have the following Spring controller

```
package de.pma.webservice.controller;

@Api(description = "Callback-Schnittstelle zu Mailjet")
@Controller
public class MailjetCallbackController extends BasicController {

    @RequestMapping(
        value = RestURIConstants.MAILJET_CALLBACK, // "mailjet/callback"
        method = RequestMethod.POST) // "The event data is sent in the POST request body using a JSON object. Its content depends on the event."
    public
    @ResponseBody
    ResponseEntity<?>
    mailjetCallback(@RequestBody MailResponse response) {
        try {
            System.out.println(response.toString());
            // TODO business logic
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

and the JSON object sent to the server is something like the following:

```
{
   "event": "open",
   "time": 1433103519,
   "MessageID": 19421777396190490,
   "email": "api@mailjet.com",
   "mj_campaign_id": 7173,
   "mj_contact_id": 320,
   "customcampaign": "",
   "CustomID": "helloworld",
   "Payload": "",
   "ip": "127.0.0.1",
   "geo": "US",
   "agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:11.0) Gecko Firefox/11.0"
}
```

With MailResponse being a simple bean (only 2 attributes for testing for now...):

```
package de.pma.webservice.model;

public class MailResponse {

    private String event;
    private String time;

    public MailResponse() {
    }

// + getters and setters        

}
```

However, when I try to post that JSON object to my controller via Postman, I always get the following exception:

```
Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: Root name 'event' does not match expected ('MailResponse') for type [simple type, class de.pma.webservice.model.MailResponse]
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@48429b77; line: 2, column: 4]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Root name 'event' does not match expected ('MailResponse') for type [simple type, class de.pma.webservice.model.MailResponse]
```

I tried finding solutions but so far nothing I found really helped (I am not very experienced with Spring :-( ) so maybe someone out there could help me with this?

Thanks in advance
Jens

Edit 1: Jackson bean configuration

```
package de.pma.webservice.config;

import ....

@ComponentScan("de.pma.webservice.controller")
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@Import(SwaggerConfig.class)
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.add(converter());
        converters.add(new org.springframework.http.converter.ResourceHttpMessageConverter());
        converters.add(new org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter());
    }

    @Bean
    public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter() {
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        converter.setObjectMapper(mapper());
        return converter;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper mapper() {
        return new CustomJacksonObjectMapper();
    }
}
```

Edit 2: Jackson object mapper

```
package de.pma.webservice.mapper;

import ...

public class CustomJacksonObjectMapper extends ObjectMapper {

    public CustomJacksonObjectMapper() {
        super();
        this.configure(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
        this.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);

        this.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.ALL, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE);
        this.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE);
        this.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.GETTER, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE);
        this.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.SETTER, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE);

        this.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
        setDateFormat(new ISO8601DateFormat());
    }
}
```

Comment: This is because the controller thinks that each field is a root level field. The JSON is expected to be wrapped as follows : `"MailResponse" : {......}`

Comment: Could you share your jackson bean configuration?

Comment: I added jackson bean configuration and object mapper. Hope this helps. How could I consume the JSON without it being wrapped in a MailResponse object?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like

```
DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, false
```

does the magic. But as we have several 3rd party services in our project, this could not be changed globally. My idea now is to create a separate web app for consuming the mailjet callbacks and leave the rest of the web application untouched.

Seems as for now, you can't tell the ObjectMapper to handle this feature differently dpending on the Spring Controller. Or at least I could not find a way :-)